# autocorrelation interpretation (annual bird surveys)

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, biostatistics, trend, population

I am following a method used by others (McCrimmon et al. 1997 Ecological Applications 7(2):581-592) to look for trends in the annual count of nesting pairs of birds at 29 nest sites over a 42 year period. We graphed the time series and the first differences (FDs) of total annual counts. FDs presumably show a trend in the population (FDs >0 show increasing, and <0 show decreasing populations). Next, We calculated a linear regression of FDs of total counts, and average values of FDs normalized to the average values of the total counts. Our data showed negative mean FDs and a negative slope, implying an accelerated rate of population decline through the time series. The next step is calculating the autocorrelation of total counts and FDs, with the assumption that ACF will provide an indication of periodicities in the time series and, finally, we will use it to calculate the correlation time statistic. We used SPSS v23.0 and followed the user manual to define the date periodicity (Data/Define date and time/Years - no subdivision of the time period into months); then waded through the ACF protocol using /Analyze/Forecasting/Sequence charts to examine the time series, followed by Analyze/Forecasting/Autocorrelations, where the variables are annual nesting pairs.

The graph of count of annual pairs and associated FDs:
[image: plot of annual pairs and FDs]

ACF Model Description
Model Name      MOD_8
Series Name 1   sum_pairs; 2 FDs total pairs
Transformation      None
Non-Seasonal Differencing   0
Seasonal Differencing       0
Length of Seasonal Period   No periodicity
Maximum Number of Lags      41
Process Assumed for Calculating the Standard Errors of the Autocorrelations     Independence(white noise)a
Display and Plot        All lags
Applying the model specifications from MOD_8
a Not applicable for calculating the standard errors of the partial autocorrelations.

[image: ACF pairs]

We are limited to posting only 2 links, but we have the PACF chart and the ACF and PACF output and charts for the FDs.

We read many of the other posts, and it appears our data are sinusoidal, with about a 20 year lag interval to the lowest inflection point, then a 20 year lag rising to flatline around 0 towards the end of the dataset. How do we interpret this chart overall, and the importance of this weak upswing? The PACFs are within the confidence intervals after year 1 and the years alternate positive and negative in an uneven number at each uptick or downtick.

Again, we are unfamiliar with how to interpret these data and will appreciate any input. We produced the same analyses for the FDs.